# Getting MySQL Connection not available when trying to get a cursor from inside a class but not from outside

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I'm running mariadb database on OS X 10.9 and trying to connect to it via python.

If I try this code it works well

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', database='account_balances')
    cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
```

I can event insert some records

but if I try the following

```
class account(object):
    _logging_to_db_enabled = False
    _database_object = None
    _database_cursor = None

def __init__(self):
    pass

def enable_logging_to_db(self):
    try:
        self._database_object = mariadb.connect(mariadb.connect(user='root', database='account_balances'))
        self._logging_to_db_enabled = True
    except self._database_object.Error as error:
        print ("Opening DB error: {}".format(error))

    self._database_cursor = self._database_object.cursor()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    testobject = account()
    testobject.enable_logging_to_db()
```

I get this error

```
File "....", line 22, in enable_logging_to_db
self._database_cursor = self._database_object.cursor()
File "<pathname_deleted>", line 1372, in cursor
raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

Anyone an idea why this is working in main but not within an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a typo/copy&paste error:

```
self._database_object = mariadb.connect(mariadb.connect(user='root', database='account_balances'))
```

It should be:

```
self._database_object = mariadb.connect(user='root', database='account_balances')
```

Comment: Oh man ;( Too stupid. Thanks a lot for this hint I was looking for a problem with the cursor.